# Workarounds to suspend (serialize) and resume a recursive generator stack?

Tags: python, recursion, tree, generator, python-3.3

I have a recursive generator function that creates a tree of ChainMap contexts, and finally does something with the context at the end of the tree. It looks like this (`parent_context` is a ChainMap, `hierarchy` is a list):

```
def recursive_generator(parent_context, hierarchy):
    next_level = hierarchy[0]
    next_level_contexts = get_contexts(next_level) # returns a list of dicts

    for context in next_level_contexts:
        child_context = parent_context.new_child().update(context)
        if next_level == hierarchy[-1]:
            yield do_something(**child_context)
        else:
            yield from recursive_generator(child_context, hierarchy[1:])
```

Now I'd like to flag one level of the hierarchy such that the operation suspends after finishing that level, serializes the state to disk to be picked up later where it left off. Is there a way to do this without losing the elegance of the recursion?

I know that you can't pickle generators, so I thought about refactoring into an iterator object. But I think `yield from` is necessary for the recursion here (edit: at least without some tedious management of the stack), so I think it needs to be a generator, no? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you seem to be exploring a tree with DFS.  so you could construct the tree in memory and make the DFS explicit.  then just store the tree and restart at the left-most node (i think?).

that's effectively "tedious management of the stack", but it has a nice picture that would help implement it (at least for me, looking at your problem as DFS of a tree makes the implementation seem fairly obvious - before i thought of it like that, it seemed quite complicated - but i may be missing something).

sorry if that's obvious and insufficient...

[edit]

```
class Inner:

    def __init__(self, context, hierarchy):
        self.children = []
        next_level = hierarchy[0]
        next_level_contexts = get_contexts(next_level)
        for context in next_level_contexts:
            child_context = parent_context.new_child().update(context)
            if next_level == hierarchy[-1]:
                self.children.append(Leaf(context))
            else:
                self.children.append(Inner(child_context, hierarchy[1:]))

    def do_something(self):
        # this will do something on the left-most leaf                         
        self.children[0].so_something()

    def prune(self):
        # this will remove the left-most leaf                                  
        if isinstance(self.children[0], Leaf):
            self.children.pop(0)
        else:
            self.children[0].prune()
            if not self.children[0]:
                self.children.pop(0)

    def __bool__(self):
        return bool(self.children)

class Leaf:

    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context

    def do_something(): 
        do_something(**self.context)
```

the code above hasn't been tested.  i ended up using classes for nodes as a tuple seemed too confusing.  you create the tree by creating the parent node.  then you can "do something" by calling `do_something`, after which you will want to remove the "done" leaf with `prune`:

```
tree = Inner(initial_context, initial_hierarchy)
while tree:
    tree.do_something()
    tree.prune()
```

i am pretty sure it will contain bugs, but hopefully it's enough to show the idea.  sorry i can't do more but i need to repot plants....

ps it's amusing that you can write code with generators, but didn't know what DFS was.  you might enjoy reading the "algorithm design manual" - it's part textbook and part reference, and it doesn't treat you like an idiot (i too have no formal education in computer science, and i thought it was a good book).

[edited to change to left-most first, which is what you had before, i think]

and alko has a good point...

Comment: No, it wasn't obvious, I don't have much experience with academic computer science, I had to look up what depth first search was. But yes, that's what I'm doing. The order's important - and I'm only interested in the nodes at the bottom of the tree (though in a sense the nodes above are taken into account via the ChainMap).

Comment: Is there a certain data structure or module you are suggesting to model the the tree in memory? I also think maybe I could put the "tree" into memory by collecting the contexts in the bottom nodes (instead of calling `do_something`), save them to a list, then run the list in sections and save the current spot. It's more important to execute the sequence of `do_something` calls lazily than the actual tree search.

Comment: @HenryS.Harrison as DFS is naturally implemented with stack, you might use simple `lists` or `collections.deque` for this task. if you prefer firsthand walk through the tree, just save visited nodes in a list: `to_visit=deque(); visited=deque(); ...; n = to_visit.popleft(); to_visit.extend(children(n)); visited.append(n);`

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that's a nice solution, and I think it would be best if I needed to retain the entire tree structure. But since I just need the leafs (in order), my solution is a little more compact and readable. Thanks for the book recommendation too. I've learned a lot just by playing around and reading documentation, but that doesn't teach you algorithms.

Comment: Andrew, I also like that I can run `do_something` at any node in the tree, I actually implemented something like that by saving the contexts in a MultiIndex pandas DataFrame (the fields of the contexts are always the same) so the user can start and stop by any index (each index = one level in the hieararchy).

Comment: @alko, your solution is nice except it's not very flexible for potentially running sections out of order or more than once (which I didn't include in my original question, I know). Anyways, I think my ultimate solution is sort of like the list version of your suggestion.

Comment: Andrew, I decided to accept your answer since the solution is more general than mine and may be more useful on the off chance someone else has a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
def recursive_generator(parent_context, hierarchy):
    next_level = hierarchy[0]
    next_level_contexts = get_contexts(next_level) # returns a list of dicts

    for context in next_level_contexts:
        child_context = parent_context.new_child().update(context)
        if next_level == hierarchy[-1]:
            yield child_context
        else:
            yield from recursive_generator(child_context, hierarchy[1:])

def traverse_tree(hierarchy):
    return list(recursive_generator(ChainMap(), hierarchy)

def do_things(contexts, start, stop):
    for context in contexts[start:stop]:
        yield do_something(**context)
```

Then I can pickle the list returned by `traverse_tree` and later load it and run it in pieces with `do_things`. This is all in a class with a lot more going on of course, but this gets to the gist of it.